# Loading issues with Ionic webview plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, audio, plugins, webview

I'm using the Ionic webview plugin for Cordova to port my HTML5 game to mobile devices, but it's having trouble loading some of the audio files. It will load a few of them, but then arbitrarily gets stuck on one.

Giving me this error:
`Uncaught (in promise) NotSupportedError: Failed to load because no supported source was found.`
I don't think it's a CORS issue since it loads some of the audio files, and in any case the webview is just requesting the audio from https://localhost which I believe is being served by the webserver that comes with the plugin, so I wouldn't think there would be any cross-origin shenanigans happening.

Has anyone run into this issue before? If so, how did you fix it?
Does anyone have any insight as to how this plugin works so I might debug it myself?

Comment: Share your Code for better understanding

Comment: No code to share really. The JavaScript that makes the request is simply `var newSound = new Audio("audio/" + fileName + fileType);`
I have a list of audio files that I iterate through and make the request on each one.